# Where does $4 come from here?

Tags: bnf

This is in [the first rule of Perl](https://github.com/mirrors/perl/blob/69f26f522d3144d15f7bf1df76cb51db6af43d05/perly.y):

```
grammar :   GRAMPROG
            {
              PL_parser->expect = XSTATE;
            }
        remember stmtseq
            {
              newPROG(block_end($3,$4));
              $$ = 0;
            }
```

How can `$4` work when there're only `3` elements on the right side?

Answer (score 0):

An embedded action (the code `{ PL_parser->expect = XSTATE; }` which occurs in the middle of the rule) counts as an element.  So there are 4 elements.  $1 is the terminal **GRAMPROG**, $2 is the embedded action, $3 is the nonterminal **remember**, and $4 is the nonterminal **stmtseq**.  (The value of $2 is whatever value is assigned to $$ inside the embedded action.  Currently it would be garbage.)

Answer (score 0):

Under the covers, yacc only really supports actions at the end of a production. So when you interleave an action `{ PL_parser->expect = XSTATE; }` in the middle of a production, yacc (or whatever descendent you're using) pulls out the action and sticks it at the end of an empty rule as such:

```
grammar: GRAMPROG $$1 remember stmtmseq
    {
        newPROG(block_end($3, $4));
        $$ = 0;
    }

$$1:
   {
       PL_parser->expect = XSTATE;
   }
```

(If your yacc variant support dumping the verbose grammar and you do that, you'll see a lot of $$1, $$2, etc. rules for actions.)

In this case the interleaved action doesn't actually assign anything to `$$`, but if it had, the `grammar` rule could have accessed the value as `$2`.